# SDL corrupt .drectve

Tags: c++, mingw, sdl

I just installed SDL and it gives me a warning that keeps it from compiling.

this is the build log:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in Graphics (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -LC:\Users\73638G75MA\Documents\SDL2-2.0.3\lib\x86 -o bin\Debug\Graphics.exe obj\Debug\main.o  -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2  
C:\Users\73638G75MA\Documents\SDL2-2.0.3\lib\x86/SDL2main.lib(./Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text[_main]+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0x0): first defined here
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

and the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `main()` function specified in your code? Seems that SDL provides it's own (different) entry point for you.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I do, I'll put program up too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I linked to the wrong SDL\include and SDL\bin, linked to the x64 one instead of the x86 one